# Making Spring Boot Jar executable throws "java.class.nonPublicPartOfAPI" Error

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have a Spring Boot app that runs fine but now I want to have it run via exec jar. I add the following to my application...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>me.Application</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Now everything seems to build (`mvn package` works) and I can run. However, when I try running `mvn install` I get...

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.revapi:revapi-maven-plugin:0.11.4:check (check) on project bot-gateway: The following API problems caused t
he build to fail:
[ERROR] java.class.nonPublicPartOfAPI: class org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarEntry: Class 'org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarEntry
' is indirectly included in the API (by the means of method return type for example) but the class is not accessible (neither public nor protected).
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Consult the plugin output above for suggestions on how to ignore the found problems
```

If I remove the maven plugin install works but it cannot be executed as jar.

What am I missing?

**Update**

I also tried...

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>me.Application</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But I still get...

> no main manifest attribute, in target\my-war.war

I can ignore the issue and get everything to build and run correctly by ignoring the issue like...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.revapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>revapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <analysisConfiguration>
                    <revapi.ignore>
                        <item>
                            <code>java.class.nonPublicPartOfAPI</code>
                        </item>
                    </revapi.ignore>
                </analysisConfiguration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But this is not an acceptable solution because if there was a legitimate issue with that I would miss it.

Comment: I strongly recommend to upgrade revapi-maven-plugin cause you are using an old version... furthermore remote maven-assembly-plugin configuration cause spring boot uses spring-boot-maven-plugin ...Why do you need a war file?

Comment: @khmarbaise so let me try to answer all of these questions. First when I try to upgrade the plugin in our private repo (we cannot directly access public repos) it gets rejected due to safety concerns. I opened up a ticket but haven't heard back yet so that is out of the question for now. I will let you know if it works when resolved.

Comment: As for the war it is just required to be that way by infra so I don't know if I can go into details because I am not sure.

Comment: The issue mentioned is a bug in the plugin ` but the class is not accessible (neither public nor protected).` cause looks like a package private class which produces the error. This means the revapi-maven-plugin needs to be upgraded... no other way ..anything else is wrong.. Why not updating a plugin which has issues? Sounds like a wrong way ....

Comment: @khmarbaise here we just have a command line tool similar to yum that we can request new deps through and apparently there are issues some may be false flags. For example it is showing an issue in dom4j not being new enough

Answer (score -1):

All you need is just default setting Spring Boot provided
e.g.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

if you want executable JAR, make sure in your pom packaging was not set to WAR

Comment: This isn't working I still get the no main manifest attribute, in target\my-war.war

Comment: can you share complete pom.xml

Comment: I can put parts on but there will be deps left off that are internal

Comment: I can also run commands to confirm plugin versions etc but the real problem is with :revapi-maven-plugin. If it wasn't for that the first one would work

Comment: it's weird that your showing target\my-war.war  and not .jar so maybe you have set <packaging>war</packaging> in you pom

Comment: Right but that is not a big deal a war is an executable jar

Comment: Like I said it works with the top one but breaks the revapi